# Shift a Single Equation Vertically

Tags: equations

I'm in the final stages of formatting my thesis and I have one final change to make which I do not know how to do.  I have an equation at the top of a page, but it's spaced as though there is text above it.  To meet my university's requirements it needs to be at the top margin.  Is there a way I can suppress the generation of white space above an equation for a single instance?  I've already tried this to no effect, does anyone have any other suggestion:

```
\begingroup
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-12pt}
\begin{equation}
equation here
\end{equation}
\endgroup
```

Comment: for such final adjustments just use `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` or whatever you need, but there should not be space  before it, if there is there is probably something wrong with the markup

Comment: in particular if you have a blank line or `\\ ` before the equation remove that as they will adversely affect the spacing at a page break.

Comment: Thank you so much, removing a blank line did it.  Its always neglecting something basic isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Never leave a blank line before a display math environment, it will produce a spurious white line paragraph that will look like vertical space but is an empty line and is not dropped at a page break and so will displace the equation causing it to appear too low.